# Why can't I access tables in a dataset by table name?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dataset

In my VB.Net desktop application, I have several places where I am accessing a table, both for reading and for updating. For example:

```
Dim tempCount As Integer = Glbl.GlobalDataSet.Tables("Profiles").Rows.Count
```

The above does not work. However, the following does:

```
Dim tempCount As Integer = Glbl.GlobalDataSet.Tables(4).Rows.Count
```

I am pretty sure it was working in th past (I have recently switched to VS 2010 - could this have anything to do with it?) but it is not working now.

How can I make the first statement work, so can access tables by table name instead of by index?

Comment: Glbl.GlobalDataSet.Tables(4) - check the name of this and see if it's what you are expecting.

Comment: Yes, of course that works.  All functions work if I use the index, but not if I use the name.  I get an exception that the Object Reference does not exist.

Comment: I was just wanting you to make sure the name displayed was the name you were trying to access it by. Never underestimate the destructive power of a capped letter that's not supposed to be capped or a typo.

Comment: Please show us the code where you are doing the "ds.add(TableName)", ie building the table.

Comment: Public Shared GlobalDataSet As DataSet
TableName = strRead.Substring(x + 6)
ds.Tables.Add(TableName)
Later after it is all populated, ds=GlobalDataSet

Comment: Put that code in with your question, please. All code should be in the question; anyone coming to help (or learn) shouldn't have to search the comments for relevant info. I think Jim wanted to see the code where you were actually assigning the string "Profiles". Everything you've shown us looks like it should be working, at least to me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the table name is assigned to the tables 4 in your dataset, if not before writing the first code part in your question change the table name like

```
Glbl.GlobalDataSet.Tables(4).TableName = "Profiles"
```

after this try getting the count of the table using table name, or while filling the database values from database to the dataset you fill it by specifying the table name.

```
DAdapter.Fill(Glbl.GlobalDataSet.Tables("Profiles"))
```

Comment: Glbl.GlobalDataSet.Tables(4).TableName gives me the right table and I cen even retrieve rows.  But Glbl.GlobalDataSet.Tables("Profiles").TableName gives me Nothing (Null)

Comment: @user989468, is it not throwing any exception to you when you try to access with using table name?

Comment: @user989468, assign the table name like I have shown in the first step. You will get your desired.

Comment: If you are talking about using Glbl.GlobalDataSet.Tables(4).TableName = "Profiles" I would then not bother naming it.  I have already named the tables when adding the table - ds.add(TableName).  I don't want to use the indexes at all because in the future if the DB structure changes, I will have to go through the code and rewrite 11 tables times about a dozen references. Ugh!

Comment: PS, @skk, yes it gives me an exception - Object Reference not found.

Answer (score 0):

It should be working, make sure that the name of the DataTable is correct. Use the property window to check then rebuild the project.